# Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: swift4

#### 前提・実現したいこと

「TableViewでTEST1を選択(タップしViewControllerに画面遷移する)したとする。
その時、遷移先のViewControllerで、TEST1と1(配列name2において、TEST1と同じ順番)をUILabelで表示させる。」
上記の内容を実現したいと考えております。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
2019-04-07 22:53:01.658174+0900 TEST[41654:1641268] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fbb2b850a00; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002f10300>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002107b40>; contentOffset: {0, -88}; contentSize: {414, 176}; adjustedContentInset: {88, 0, 34, 0}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<TEST.TableViewController: 0x7fbb2ac0a290>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fd06fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010658bac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fd0482 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105fd9927 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000010aa8d99f -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 433
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000010aaa06bf -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 911
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000010aaa0b65 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 73
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000010aa68d20 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2870
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010aa88e37 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 165
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010ad359c1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1417
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c2a6eae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 173
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c2abb88 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 396
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c2b7ee4 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 72
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c2273aa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 328
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c25e584 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 608
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a880ccb __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 128
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f37aec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f372b0 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f31b34 __CFRunLoopRun + 1252
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f31302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fb692fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a867ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    22  TEST                                0x0000000105ca5cfb main + 75
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001093d8541 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //cellのlabelに代入するString
    let name1:[String] = ["TEST1","TEST2","TEST3","TEST4"]
    let name2:[String] = ["1","2","3","4"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    //遷移先のViewControllerに渡す変数
    var giveData: String = ""
    var giveData2:String = ""

    //sectionの数を返す数
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // sectionの数を返す関数乗せる
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return name1.count

//        }else if  section == 1{
//            return name2.count
//
        }else{
            return 0

    }

    //sectionの高さを返す
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    //sectionに載せる文字列を返す関数
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "section\(section)"
    }

    //cellの情報を書き込む関数
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        //ここでcellのlabelに値を入れる
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            cell.name.text = name1[indexPath.item]

//        }else{
//            cell.name.text = name2[indexPath.item]
//        }

        return cell
    }

    // cellが押されたときに呼ばれる関数
    // 画面遷移の処理もここで書いている

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //押された時のcellのlabelの文字列をViewControllerに渡したいので、giveDataに入れる

        if indexPath.section == 0{
            giveData = name1[indexPath.item]
            giveData2 = name2[indexPath.item]

      }
                print(indexPath)
 //       else{
//
//        }

        //Segueを使った画面遷移をおこな関数
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil)


    }

    //遷移先のViewControllerにデータを渡す関数

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Segue"{

            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.receiveData = giveData
            vc.receiveData2 = giveData2
        }
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

//    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//        return 0
//    }
//
//    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
//        return 0
//    }

    /*
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
}
}
```

#### 試したこと

breakpointを打ち、上記のコードから、問題の箇所を探しました。しかし、最後の}でエラーが出たものの、
それより前ではエラーが出ません。
定数や変数の代入には問題が内容に見えます。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/183319

Comment: とりあえず、あちこち闇雲にコメントアウトされているせいで、`{`と`}`が正しくバランスしていません。ソースコードの最後に意味不明のまま`}`を付け加えるのではなく、正しい修正を行ってください。Cmd-Aで全選択した後、Ctrl-Iで再インデントして、インデントがおかしい部分を解消してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。正しく動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
}の位置を正したことで解決しました。